# Calculator using all the input data on a single line

Tags: c#

- 

(later edit)

Just finished this assignment.  I was limited to using System and using System.collections.Generic. Nothing else. I ended up using a List<> from the from the  collections.Generic. and the principles of Polish Notation.    After every "Encounter" of a operation sign (+-/*) I used the index - 1 and - 2 to get the previous 2 numbers and make the operation. Then I used .Insert to insert the result at the current index, afterwards I used .Remove to substract from the list the numbers and the operator which I just used and after I continued with the recursive function on the new list obtained starting with the index from 0 again. The polish notation articles posted in the comments helped me the most to understand the logic behind this

*

I'm trying to figure out from the past several days a way to implement the following logic into a c# program. Using only System.

This is a small console calculator where the input is inserted on a single line in the console.
For example the following input `+ / * + 65 32 46 2 - 1 1.25` should be translated into a math operation looking like this => `((65 + 32) * 46) / 2 + (1 - 1.25)`

Another example would be `* + 3 2 - 9.5 6.5`: this should be calculated in the following order `3 + 2 * (9.5 - 6.5)`.

Another example `/ + 5 3 2` equals with => `(5 + 3) / 2`

I have to make the function recursive.

I figured out how to make it if all the operations sings are in front of the digits in the input. (I just separate the operator list and inverse it and I get two separate lists: one containing the operation signs and the other containing the numbers). What I'm struggling is to figure out a way to do the operations if there is a math sign in between the numbers (like in the first an the second example).

I don't necessarily need a code for this, maybe an explanation or if somebody could point me to the right direction where I can read about some algorithm / math formula or something that could help me better understand how to implement this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is one supposed to infer the order of operations from the jumble of numbers / operators in your input?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi It looks like it is [Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) (the opposite of [RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)).

Comment: you aren't passing in enough information.  How on earth would someone infer that division in your first example, when every other location you don't have  a symbol, it's multiplied?

Comment: @JohnLord There is a `/` in the first example, it plainly refers to division. And there are `*` in all the others when multiplication is desired, there are no implicit operations.

Comment: It might help if you translated so the order of operations is explicit e.g. translate your prefix notation into LISP: `(+ (/ (* (+ 65 32) 46) 2) (- 1 1.25))` for the first example.

Comment: @NetMage I would guess it's a [prefix expression](https://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/cs212/fix.html).

Comment: https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2021/04/polish-notation.html

Comment: sorry i see it now.  parsing 2 and 3 make sense but  i don't see still how that would get parsed in the first one.  I would have to see it diagrammed.

Comment: @JohnLord Does my LISP version make it easier?

Comment: @NetMage as it turns out Polish Notation is another name for it, always learning.

Comment: @JohnLord this is a classical application for a binary tree-

Comment: @John Lord Well, this is a problem I'm working through. Unfortunately I don't have more information, I just have that info and I have to work with it to end up with the desired output. The program needs to make the calculations in the order from the examples. I'm currently reading about Polis Notation, thank you for the suggestions

Comment: Is this homework? Otherwise, you shouldn't need to use recursion... just use a stack.

Comment: So no `System.Linq.Expressions` allowed? Because I can parse the above into an expression tree.

Comment: No System.Linq allowed. I have to "squeeze" everything just using System. The idea of this (and other tasks that I have) is to fully understand everything that can be done just using System. But I think that I now heave enough info and I can get trough with finishing this calculator.

Comment: @NetMage, yes it's kind of a homework. It's an assignment  from a c# course I'm taking, I'm currently on a chapter where I have to use recursion on every task.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't like classes / assignments like that. I don't agree they teach appropriate language usage :)

Answer (score 3):

The normal method of evaluating Polish Notation expressions doesn't require recursion, you use a stack (like Forth or RPN) and evaluate as you go.

An easy way to create a recursive version is to consider the expression language [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) then crafting a [recursive descent parser](https://www.engr.mun.ca/%7Etheo/Misc/exp_parsing.htm) from the grammer.

For example, a possible BNF would be:

```
expr = op arg arg
op = [+-*/] // cheating; use regex to describe terminal
arg = number | expr
number = [0-9]+ // using Regex to describe terminal
```

So now you would create methods for each element:

```
double expr() {
    string opStr = op();
    double arg1 = arg();
    double arg2 = arg();

    double ans;
    switch (opStr) {
        case "+":
            ans = arg1+arg2;
            break;
        // case and so on
    }

    return ans;
}

static string operators = "+-*/";
string op() {
    if (operators.Contains(peekChar()))
        return nextCharAsStr();
    else
        throw new Exception("Missing operator");
}

double arg() {
    double? num = number();
    if (num.HasValue)
        return num.Value;
    else
        return expr();
}

double? number() {
    string ans = "";
    while (Char.IsDigit(peekChar()))
       ans += nextCharAsStr();
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ans))
        return null;
    else
        return Double.Parse(ans);
}
```

NOTE: Whitespace and end of string is left as an exercise to the reader.

You could also use a tokenizer that extracts terminals from the string instead of working directly with characters in the parser terminal methods.

Comment: Why is `JavaScript` polluting C# code? Lack of braces around _all_ cases, no capitalization of methods, Using the type instead of the alias for build-in functions like `double.Parse()`, and failure to use appropriate `ArgumentException` where required. My eyes hurt..

Comment: @JohnAlexiou In C# braces aren't required around a `case`. Methods aren't capitalized because they map to non-terminals in the grammar, which is also not capitalized, and because they are private methods. I disagree that `ArgumentException` is appropriate for a missing operator error.

Answer (score 0):

There are different kinds of recursion. The most common (code recursion) is probably what you're asking about, wherein a function (or set of functions) call each other until some sort of exit condition is reached.

For this, I'd go with more of a data recursive approach. This version only supports single-digit operands and binary operators.

(Really bad pseudocode below).

```
stack<char> operators;
stack<char> operands;

for(var i=input.Length-1; i>=0; --i)
{

    var c = input[i]; 
    if (Char.IsDigit(c)) /// note that this only handles single-digit numbers.
       operands.push(c);
    else 
       operators.push(c);
    
    if (operators.count >= 1 && operands.count >= 2)
    {
       var operator = operators.pop();
       /// handle binary operators
       left = operands.pop();
       right = operands.pop();
       switch(operator) {
          case '+' : result = left + right; break;
          case '-' : result = left - right; break;
          case '*' : result = left * right; break;
          case '/' : result = left / right; break;
       }
       operands.push(result);
    }        
}

var result = operands.pop();
```

When that completes, your `operands` stack should have only one item which is the result of the expression. and `operators` should be empty.
If you have leftover operators, then there weren't enough values in the input. If you have more than one value in operands, there weren't enough operators in the input. If you have zero operands (ie, no result), then there weren't any in the input to start with.

For a real implementation, you'd want to parse the string to get multi-digit operands, handle unary operators, ignore whitespace, etc.

Edit: reversed the loop direction.

Comment: Don't you need a `while` loop instead of an `if` to finish parsing the operator stack when you have a lot of operators pushed and reach the end of the string?

Comment: @NetMage If you have anything left in operators when you hit the end of the string, then the input was ill-formed. (Too many operators or not enough operands.)

Comment: Note that in C# everthing is capitalized, except for local variables and fields. So it is `Stack<T>` and `.Pop()` ..

Comment: @JohnAlexiou It's pseudocode. `operator` is also a reserved word, and the code doesn't include any initialization, etc. :)

Comment: Not sure if that would be true if it worked correctly, which it does not. It evaluates `+ * 6 3 - 3 1` as 16 when the correct answer is 20 because it evaluates `- 18 3` instead of `- 3 1` as it goes through.

Comment: @NetMage Hmmm.. Okay, I might be stuck in some sort of weird hybrid RPN mode-of-thinking. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @NetMage I reversed the loop direction and operand pop order. SEEMS fine to me now, but I've probably missed something. If so, I'll just nuke the answer.

Comment: I think that should work - I did notice running the prefix notation backwards becomes an RPN evaluation.

Comment: Seems pretty similar with the example in java from the link posted by @stuartd (thecrazyprogrammer.com/2021/04/polish-notation.html)   I think I got the logic behind and the lecture about Polish Notation was very helpful in clearing some stuff out. I'm currently at work but as soons as I get home I'll get back on this assignment and update you guys. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

So you want something like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Expression expr = Parse("+ / * + 65 32 46 2 - 1 1.25");
        Console.WriteLine($"f = {expr}");
        // f = ((((65 + 32) * 46) / 2) + (1 - 1.25))
        Func<double> f = Compile(expr);
        Console.WriteLine($"f = {f()}");
        // f = 2230.75
    }
    public static Func<double> Compile(Expression expr)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda(expr).Compile() as Func<double>;
    }
    public static Expression Parse(string input)
    {
        var tokens = new Tokenizer(input);
        return Parse(tokens);
    }
```

There are two parts this.

1. First split the input into substrings using the white space. Use `input.Split()` for that. Then, scan the parts from right to left (from last to first) and extract tokens. A token is a  substring that might represent a number or an operation (or a variable if you extend the code below). This is the job of `Tokenizer` class, the implements `IEnumerable<TokenInfo>` to act as a collection. A `TokenInfo` is a data type that describes each token, and it contains the following:

   - An identifying tag of enum `Token.Number`, `Token.Operator` or `Token.End`
   - The `string` text identifying the operator (when applicable)
   - The `double` value representing a number (when applicable)

     ```
       public enum Token
       {
           Unknown,
           Number,
           Operator,
           End
       }

       public struct TokenInfo
       {
           public TokenInfo(Token token)
           {
               Token=token;
               Text = string.Empty;
               Value = 0;
           }

           public TokenInfo(string op) : this(Token.Operator)
           {
               Text = op;
           }
           public TokenInfo(double value) : this(Token.Number)
           {
               Value = value;
           }
           public TokenInfo(Token token, string text) : this(token)
           {
               Text = text;
           }
           public Token Token { get; }
           public string Text { get; }
           public double Value { get; }
       }

       public class Tokenizer : IEnumerable<TokenInfo>
       {
           readonly string[] operators = new[] { "+", "-", "*", "/" };
           readonly List<TokenInfo> tokens;
           public Tokenizer(string input)
           {
               tokens = new List<TokenInfo>();
               string[] parts = input.Split(' ');
               for (int i = parts.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
               {
                   if (operators.Contains(parts[i]))
                   {
                       tokens.Add(new TokenInfo(parts[i]));
                   }
                   else if (double.TryParse(parts[i], out var x))
                   {
                       tokens.Add(new TokenInfo(x));
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       tokens.Add(new TokenInfo(Token.Unknown, parts[i]));
                   }
               }
               tokens.Add(new TokenInfo(Token.End));
           }

           public IEnumerator<TokenInfo> GetEnumerator()
           {
               return tokens.GetEnumerator();
           }

           System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
           {
               return GetEnumerator();
           }
       }
     ```
2. Parse the list of tokens and built the expression tree. Keep a `Stack<Expression>` and assume the top expression is always the result of the previous operation. Also what gets returned in the end is the top of the stack, if it is only one expression tall. Otherwise, there is an imbalance in the operators and/or the values.

   Do the following for each `Token` type

   - `Token.Number` parse the value of the number using `double.TryParse()` and add a `ConstantExpression` on the stack
   - `Token.Operator` pull two values from the top of the stack and add an appropriate `BinaryEpression` to the stack. Possible options are `Expression.Add()`, `Expression.Subtract()`, `Expression.Multiply()`, and `Expression.Divide()`
   - `Token.End` return the last expression of the top of the stack.

     ```
      public static Expression Parse(IEnumerable<TokenInfo> tokens)
      {
          Stack<Expression> stack = new Stack<Expression>();
          foreach (var item in tokens)
          {
              switch (item.Token)
              {
                  case Token.Number:
                      {
                          var expr = Expression.Constant(item.Value, typeof(double));
                          stack.Push(expr);
                      }
                      break;
                  case Token.Operator:
                      {
                          var arg1 = stack.Pop();
                          var arg2 = stack.Pop();
                          switch (item.Text)
                          {
                              case "+":
                                  stack.Push(Expression.Add(arg1, arg2));
                                  break;
                              case "-":
                                  stack.Push(Expression.Subtract(arg1, arg2));
                                  break;
                              case "*":
                                  stack.Push(Expression.Multiply(arg1, arg2));
                                  break;
                              case "/":
                                  stack.Push(Expression.Divide(arg1, arg2));
                                  break;
                              default:
                                  throw new NotSupportedException($"Invalid operator {item.Text}.");
                          }
                      }
                      break;
                  case Token.End:
                      {
                          if (stack.Count != 1)
                          {
                              throw new InvalidOperationException("Imbalanced expression tree.");
                          }
                          return stack.Pop();
                      }
              }
          }
          throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid expression.", nameof(tokens));
      }
     ```
3. Optionally the `Expression` can be compiled into a function, using the `Compile()` function above. This code assumes there are no `ParameterExpression` nodes in the expression tree which would need to be accounted for as arguments to the compiled function.

   The addition of variables in the expression and the subsequent compilation into unary or binary functions is pretty straightforward. Add a `Token` for a variable, produce an appropriate `TokenInfo` when a string that is not an operator is encountered in the tokenizer and then add `ParameterExpression` objects to the stack, just like numeric values are added. The compilation parts need references to these parameters from the tree so a custom [`ExpressionVistor`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/232697/36785) would be needed to extract those nodes.